# Porque un var_dump me devuelve un array vacio y un objeto?

Tags: php

resulta que cuando hago var_dump de una variable que recibo de un webservice recibo esto:

```
$ta = $this->GetServiceTA("ws_sr_padron_a4");
var_dump($ta->token);
```

> array(0) { } object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (1) {   [0]=>   string(744)
>   "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"
>   }

Como hago para de ese resultado obtener el string sin mas?

archivo xml del cual quiero obtener los datos:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<loginTicketResponse version="1">
    <header>
        <source>CN=wsaahomo, O=AFIP, C=AR, SERIALNUMBER=CUIT 33693450239</source>

        <uniqueId>1024476891</uniqueId>
        <generationTime>2017-11-23T09:47:07.779-03:00</generationTime>
        <expirationTime>2017-11-23T21:47:07.779-03:00</expirationTime>
    </header>
    <credentials>
        <token>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</token>
        <sign>DOfImTTBPSI8tlTMf6sWbfTXGj4VD4SK0Nc7Vv7FFP2poNk3ahTOGGf6yUhCkpJ7LmmcCr4s2UaeXJIikGwNhDvHvPkYnuF4iyKLhJqCmYnFyk7eSs2cIZ7U/hhIWbuwJTmrIW+Fbm1TgndF8zxeXvMNleHlzrzMbf90BO8xUlQ=</sign>
    </credentials>
</loginTicketResponse>
```

Comment: no, no estoy haciendo ningun var_dump antes, el codigo es: 

$ta = $this->GetServiceTA("ws_sr_padron_a4");
  var_dump($ta->token);

Comment: No, a mi tambien me sorprende que me envie un array vacio y despues un objeto

Comment: obtengo el mismo resultado

Comment: no, como seria SoapUI?

Comment: Mira, estoy intentando consumir https://awshomo.afip.gov.ar/sr-padron/webservices/personaServiceA4?wsdl
Utilizando https://wsaahomo.afip.gov.ar/ws/services/LoginCms como  WSAA, eso genera un TA.xml de este tipo:

Comment: como pongo el contenido de un archivo xml aca?

Comment: bueno, ahi lo puse. ese archivo xml lo levanto asi:

$TA = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('ta.xml'));

luego hago un var_dump($TA->credentials->token); y me trae lo que digo

Comment: para ejecutar la funcion getPersona de https://awshomo.afip.gov.ar/sr-padron/webservices/personaServiceA4?wsdl necesito poder tener el token y el sign limpios, se entiende?

Comment: claro, de ahi mi pregunta... desde las 11 de la mañana estoy intentando, me quiero morir :(

Answer (score 1):

Los objetos de tipo SimpleXMLElement [y sus hijos](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) no se comportan propiamente como objetos.

> Note: SimpleXML has made a rule of adding iterative properties to most
>   methods. **They cannot be viewed using var_dump()** or anything else which
>   can examine objects.

En mi caso, prefiero usar librerías como [Kint](https://github.com/kint-php/kint) en vez de var_dump justamente por eso (y porque Kint es muy útil)

Para tu caso de uso, el valor del token deberás castearlo a string haciendo:

```
var_dump($TA->credentials->token->__toString());
```

Aunque también se puede convertir el SimpleXMLElement en un array asociativo y examinar las llaves anidadas.

**Edit**: Al menos según tu descripción del problema, el siguiente ćodigo sería equivalente

```
<?php

$string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<loginTicketResponse version="1">
    <header>
        <source>CN=wsaahomo, O=AFIP, C=AR, SERIALNUMBER=CUIT 33693450239</source>

        <uniqueId>1024476891</uniqueId>
        <generationTime>2017-11-23T09:47:07.779-03:00</generationTime>
        <expirationTime>2017-11-23T21:47:07.779-03:00</expirationTime>
    </header>
    <credentials>
        <token>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</token>
        <sign>DOfImTTBPSI8tlTMf6sWbfTXGj4VD4SK0Nc7Vv7FFP2poNk3ahTOGGf6yUhCkpJ7LmmcCr4s2UaeXJIikGwNhDvHvPkYnuF4iyKLhJqCmYnFyk7eSs2cIZ7U/hhIWbuwJTmrIW+Fbm1TgndF8zxeXvMNleHlzrzMbf90BO8xUlQ=</sign>
    </credentials>
</loginTicketResponse>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

// $xml = simplexml_load_string($string); Esto es equivalente


var_dump($xml->credentials->token->__toString());
```

Y esto me arroja

> string(744)
>   "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"

De manera que si tu código se comporta distinto es que hay algo diferente en el input con que generas el SimpleXMLElement. ¿Algún contenido extra en el archivo? Tal vez espacios en blanco?

Comment: El siguiente codigo: 
$TA = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($this->RES_FOLDER.'TA-ws_sr_padron_a4.xml'));
  var_dump($TA->credentials->token->__toString()); 

me sigue devolviendo:

array(0) { } string(744) "PD94bWwgdmV..."

Comment: Ahi instale Kint y al hacer "Kint::dump($TA);" me sigue saiendo al principio de todo "array(0) { }" :(

Comment: Añadí más información a mi respuesta mostrando lo que arroja la prueba que hice.